# Compiling AS3 program issue with .ttf file in library

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am getting an error trying to compile an AS3 project:

Error: Unable to transcode ../lib/Arial.ttf.

Original Code:

```
[ Embed(source= "../lib/Arial.ttf", fontName = "ArialFont", advancedAntiAliasing="true", embedAsCFF="false", fontWeight = "bold", mimeType="application/x-font")]
    private var ArialFontClass:Class;
```

I know very little AS3 so was hoping this was any easy fix with respect to font types or that someone could at least point in a direction to investigate.

Do I need to find a particular folder and look for a file? If I don't have it where do I get it? Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check:

- is your source path correct?
- does that Arial font actually contain bold glyphs? It may help to remove the `fontWeight` attribute or switch the source to an actual bold version of the font.